# Increasing Database Size, how much and when?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-administration

I have worked in SQL Server for the past ~10 years, always on the development side, but I find myself in the DBA position. I am looking at our main database, small 90GB, 30GB for the log and only 6GB(~6%) free. From what I can tell the server has a 2TB drive and about 1.6TB are free. From my basic understanding of databases, I should have at least 20% free space to avoid performance issues. It seems I could easily add 270GB (3x current size) to the database, totally 360GB, which would give me 276GB(76%) Free space. My biggest question is, should I take more? Should I increase the log by the same amount(%) or just let it autogrow?

I would guess the 276GB would last at least 5 years. I also wanted to ask the risks of change the database size, to be more exact the risks of changing it during the work day?

Comment: Is this in full recovery mode with tlog backups? If so, how frequent? if the tlog backups are frequent then the log file probably won't grow much, so adding a ton of space would be wasted disk. Similarly with the data files, if they aren't growing often, and aren't growing by large amounts, your fragmentation and resources to auto grow wouldn't be a big notice. If you are growing daily or something, then i'd look to adjust those growth rates. Make sure the files grow EVENLY though. Lastly, I'd post this on dba.stackexchange (hence my vote to xfer)

Comment: The database is backing up every night, as for growth, I am not sure how much, maybe the issue is the threshold for growth is too low? I guess it just bothers me to have 6% free space, when you have a server with 17x the database size free.

Comment: I can understand that. There is a big difference in the data file and log file though so try and keep them separate in your mind. When you do a log backup it releases that space so if you are backing up the log ever 5 min, or hour, or whatever to hit your RPO then you probably won’t see bloating. Frequent auto growth is bad. Growing by % is bad too as each froth is larger and can become huge. But I frequent and static size growth isn’t a big issue. I’d reclaim that space for something else you need like TEMPDB

Comment: @scsimon what is your opinion of when to make the change? I will most likely leave the log file as is and let it auto grow as it has been, but for the database I would really like to at least double it's size, is there a problem with doing it in the middle of the work day? The gut says "please god don't"

Comment: The log shouldn't be growing constantly. If it is, then i suspect you are in FULL recovery model and aren't doing LOG backups. If this is the case, then you need to start doing LOG backups or swap to SIMPLE recovery model if your RPO is > how ever frequent your full backups are running. I'm an advocate of never doing anything during business hours where a user could see an impact. But you shouldn't see any here. Resizing just provides allocation space for pages so you should see a high unallocated percentage if you run the disk report. This is seperate from unused space.